# Problema Nuget: No se pudo recuperar información sobre "Xamarin.Forms" del origen remoto

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget

llevo varios días sin poder resolver este problema.

cuando creo una solución Xamarin.Forms, cuando Visual Studio 2017 genera los proyectos, en el proyecto princiapl (app1) me sale un triangulo amarillo en las dependecias/Nuget de Xamarin.Forms y Dependencia/SDK de NETStandarLibrary (2.0.3).
[image: Captura triangulo amarillo]

Esto ocasiona que desde los archivos de C# del proyecto no me reconozca los USING, y la herencia a ContentPage etc.
[image: Error CS0246 en archivo C#]

Lo peor de todo es que si intento reinstalar el Nuget Xamarin.Forms en el proyecto, me es imposible. Me dice lo siguiente:

No se pudo recuperar información sobre "Xamarin.Forms" del origen remoto 
"https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=230477/FindPackagesById()?id='Xamarin.Forms'&semVerLevel=2.0.0".
  El contenido en "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=230477/FindPackagesById()?id='Xamarin.Forms'&semVerLevel=2.0.0" no es XML válido.
  Por razones de seguridad, la DTD está prohibida en este documento XML. Para habilitar el procesamiento de la DTD, establezca la propiedad DtdProcessing de 
XmlReaderSettings en Parse y pase la configuración al método XmlReader.Create.
[image: error dtd xmlreader]

No se donde tengo que cambiar esa configuración.

El caso es que si agrego a la solución un proyecto, por ejemplo WPF, y agrego el Nuget Xamarin.Forms, no me da ningún problema y lo agrega sin problema, pero en el proyecto Xamarin me sale lo anteriormente descrito.

He probado a desinstalar VisualStudio 2017 completamente (borrando claves de registro de windows etc), desinstalando paquete Xamarin y volviendo a reinstalar, pero sigue sin funcionar.

Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Solo se me ocurre verificar que en tu proyecto el <TargetFrameworkVersion> sea el mismo a lo que aparece en el packages.config